# code in adal.js acquireToken never fires

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I'm having this code in a plain script web part on a classic SharePoint Online page. I get the user but when I'm running the `authContext.acquireToken` the code inside that callback is never run. I dont get any error messages or something like that. What have I missed??

The code in rows 32 - 42 never runs. Does someone recognize this?

http://pastebin.ca/3945451